# Remove "x" number of characters from a string?

Tags: python, string

In Python: How do I write a function that would remove "x" number of characters from the beginning of a string?

For instance if my string was "gorilla" and I want to be able remove two letters it would then return "rilla".

OR if my string was "table" and I wanted to remove the first three letters it would return "le".

Please help and thank you everyone!

Comment: Use [slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/1903116). `string[2:]` or `string[3:]`

Comment: `s = 'gorilla`; s[3:]`.

Comment: _How do I write a function .._ -- Such a innocent question and no answers?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this syntax called slices

```
s = 'gorilla'
s[2:]
```

will return

```
'rilla'
```

see also [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)